# Creating associations between subclasses (STI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class User and subclasses Student and Teacher (using STI).

I want to create a has_and_belongs_to_many association between Student and Teacher. Please let me know how I can create a join table to complete this association.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration:

```
class CreateStudentsTeachersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students_teachers, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :student_id
      t.integer :teacher_id
    end
  end
end
```

Teacher model:

```
class Teacher < User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students, join_table: :students_teachers
end
```

Student model:

```
class Student < User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers, join_table: :students_teachers
end
```

Comment: Just curious, Student and Teacher will not have their own tables right? I believe they will just have entries in the "users" table? So, where do student_id and teacher_id come from?

Comment: Yes, single "users" table.
By default foreign key names in habtm join table are class names in snake-case plus "_id". They also can be specified using "foreign_key" and "association_foreign_key" options.

Comment: Does that mean that student_id is actually the user_id in the "users" table?

Comment: "student_id" and "teacher_id" point to primary key of "users" table.

Comment: Thanks! Is it necessary to mention "join_table: :students_teachers"? Or is that the default?

Comment: By default join table name will be "users_users". It doesn't use class names of STI models. At least in 4.2. I don't know why.